# `multiple-value-call` in Scheme

Tags: scheme, macros

Common Lisp has a "special operator" called [`multiple-value-call`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_multip.htm), which does something similar to Scheme's `call-with-values` but with a nicer syntax, and allowing multiple producers ([unlike `call-with-values`](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/ticket/87)). So I thought I'd try to implement `multiple-value-call` in Scheme, using `call-with-values` (dressed up here as [`receive`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-8/srfi-8.html)) behind the scenes:

```
(define-syntax multiple-value-collect
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((multiple-value-collect) '())
    ((multiple-value-collect expr next ...)
     (receive vals expr
       (cons vals (multiple-value-collect next ...))))))

(define-syntax multiple-value-call
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((multiple-value-call func expr ...)
     (apply func (concatenate! (multiple-value-collect expr ...))))))
```

Is there a better (more idiomatic, performant, etc.) way to implement this? (`concatenate!` is from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html), and `receive` is from [SRFI 8](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-8/srfi-8.html).)